# Jackson parses a map of strings to a declared class as a map of strings to maps. How do I make it create objects of the declared class instead?

Tags: kotlin, jackson, jackson-databind

I'm using jackson-module-kotlin:2.11.2 to parse some YAML. I'm trying to produce objects which contain a map, whose values are objects of a class that I have declared. This map instead contains values which are HashMaps.

Here are my declarations:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.readValue

object Parser {
    // ObjectMapper is thread safe as long as we don't mess with the config after this declaration.
    val mapper: ObjectMapper = ObjectMapper(YAMLFactory()).registerKotlinModule()
        .registerModule(JavaTimeModule())
        .registerModule(nullMapDeserialiserModule)
        .registerModule(SimpleModule().setDeserializerModifier(ValidatingDeserializerModifier()))
        // When parsing timestamps, we don't want to lose the offset information
        .disable(DeserializationFeature.ADJUST_DATES_TO_CONTEXT_TIME_ZONE)
        // We would prefer an error if we're trying to store a float in an int
        .disable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_FLOAT_AS_INT)
        // If a primitive field (like Int) is non-nullable (as in the Kotlin meaning), then we don't want nulls being converted to 0
        .enable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_NULL_FOR_PRIMITIVES)
        // Because enums could change order in future versions (if we keep them in lexicographic order, for example),
        // we don't want the client to expect that they can give us the ordinal value of the enum.
        .enable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_NUMBERS_FOR_ENUMS)
        // When serialising schedule expressions, don't include null values
        .setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)

    @Throws(JsonProcessingException::class)
    inline fun <reified T: Any> deserialise(yaml: String): T = mapper.readValue(yaml)

}

data class ListValue (
    val listValueKey: String,
    val someOtherValue: Int
)

data class ExpectedValue (
    val expectedValueKey: String,
    val list: List<ListValue>
)

data class TestClass (
    val testClassKey: String,
    @param:JsonDeserialize(contentAs = ExpectedValue::class)
    val testMap: Map<String, ExpectedValue>
)
```

Here is my test case:

```
@Test
fun `map parse test`() {
    val testObj: TestClass? = RuleParser.deserialise(
        //language=YAML
        """
          testClassKey: the-key
          testMap:
              key1:
                expectedValueKey: subKey1
                list: 
                  - listValueKey: someKey1
                    someOtherValue: 5
                  - listValueKey: anotherKey1
                    someOtherValue: 6
              key2:
                expectedValueKey: subKey2
                list: 
                  - listValueKey: someKey2
                    someOtherValue: 7
                  - listValueKey: anotherKey2
                    someOtherValue: 8
        """
    )

    assertTrue(testObj is TestClass)
    assert(testObj.testMap is HashMap)
    assertNotNull(testObj.testMap["key1"])
    assert(testObj.testMap["key1"] is ExpectedValue)
    assertEquals(
        ExpectedValue(
            expectedValueKey = "subKey1",
            list = listOf(ListValue("someKey1", 5), ListValue("anotherKey1", 6))
        ),
        testObj.testMap["key1"]
    )
}
```

Currently, this test is failing on the final assertion, with the following error

```
Expected :ExpectedValue(expectedValueKey=subKey1, list=[ListValue(listValueKey=someKey1, someOtherValue=5), ListValue(listValueKey=anotherKey1, someOtherValue=6)])
Actual   :{expectedValueKey=subKey1, list=[{listValueKey=someKey1, someOtherValue=5}, {listValueKey=anotherKey1, someOtherValue=6}]}
```

This is clearly not what I expected. If I instead parse a list of a declared class, this works correctly (example test follows).

```
@Test
fun `list parse test`() {
    val testObj: ExpectedValue? = RuleParser.deserialise(
        //language=YAML
        """
            expectedValueKey: subKey1
            list: 
              - listValueKey: someKey1
                someOtherValue: 5
              - listValueKey: anotherKey1
                someOtherValue: 6
        """
    )

    assertTrue(testObj is ExpectedValue)
    assertTrue(testObj.list[0] is ListValue)
    assertEquals(
        ListValue("someKey1", 5),
        testObj.list[0]
    )
}
```

So I'm a bit surprised that it is possible to parse a generic list in this way, but not a map. How do I get Jackson to create the map values that I expect, rather than HashMaps?

Answer (score 0):

Your deserializer function is wrong. You must use the reified generic type in `readValue` method:

```kotlin
inline fun <reified T: Any> deserialise(yaml: String): T = mapper.readValue(yaml, T::class.java)
```

Comment: The alternative would be to use the `readValue<reified T>` extension function from the Jackson Kotlin module. It's not clear from the OP whether that function is imported or not.

Comment: Sorry, yes, that function from the Jackson Kotlin module is what I am calling.

Answer (score 0):

While it is odd that the annotation is needed at all (since it is not needed for lists of a declared type), it does work if the annotation is used as follows:

```
@field:JsonDeserialize(`as` = HashMap::class, contentAs = ExpectedValue::class)
```

This was not clear at first, because that javadoc for `contentAs` does not mention that `as` is also required.